# Show that $B(1-t) - B(1)$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, solution-verification

I need a check on the following exercise. In particular, I'd like to be sure that points ii), iii) are okay.

> Let   $(B_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Prove that the process $W_t=B(1-t) - B(1)$ defined for $t \in [0,1]$ is a *standard Brownian motion*

---

i) First I can see that $W(0)=B(1) - B(1)=0$ a.s.

ii) I need to check the the increments are independent. To this aim, I fix a partition of $[0,1]$, $0<t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_n$ and consider the increments $(W_{t_1}, W_{t_2} - W_{t_1}, \ldots, W_{t_n} - W_{t_{n-1}})$

I have that $$W_{t_{i}} - W_{t_{i-1}} = B(1 - t_i) - B(1 - t_{i-1})$$

and $$W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i) = B(1 - t_{i+1}) - B(1-t_i)$$

I need to check they're independent: since both of them are normally distributed, to check the independence is enough to check that the covariance is $0$. Moreover, since $B$ is a Brownian motion, I can use the fact that

$Cov(B_t, B_s)= s \wedge t$.

Hence $$Cov(B(1-t_i) - B(1-t_{i+1} ), B(1-t_{i-1})  - B(1-t_i)) = \\
(1-t_i) \wedge (1-t_{i-1}) - (1-t_{i+1}) \wedge (1-t_{i-1}) - (1-t_i) \wedge (1-t_i) + (1-t_{i+1}) \wedge (1- t_i) = 0$$

Hence the increments are independent.

iii) I need to show that for evert $0\leq s <t$: $W(t) - W(s) - N(0,t-s)$

I have that $W(t) - W(s) = B(1-t) - B(1-s)$. Now I have that $1-t< 1 -s$, therefore I note that $$ B(1-t) - B(1-s) = -(B(1-s) - B(1-t)) $$

Now I see that the right hand side has **normal law** since it's an increment of the Brownian motion. Moreover, I have that it's mean is clearly $0$, while the variance is $t-s$

Therefore $W(t) - W(s) - N(0, t-s)$.

(iv) *Path continuity*

I have that $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is continuous for $P$-almost every $\omega$. Hence, the function $$t \mapsto B_{1-t}(\omega) - B(1)$$ is continuous, since is obtained from $B_t$ by a traslation and adding a constant $B(1)$.

**Edit**

To show it's a  Gaussian process, I can note the following:

first I note that $(B(1-t_n), B(1-t_{n-1}), \ldots, B(1-t_1), B(1))$ is a Gaussian vector (since $B$ is a Brownian motion). Therefore, I can see

$\begin{pmatrix} W(t_1) \\ \vdots \\ W(t_n) \end{pmatrix}=T((B(1-t_n), B(1-t_{n-1}), \ldots, B(1-t_1), B(1)))$

where $T$ is the linear map $T(x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n)=(x_{n-1} - x_n,x_{n-2} - x_n, \ldots, x_1 - x_n )$.

Hence, since it's the image via a linear map of a Gaussian vector, $\begin{pmatrix} W(t_1) \\ \vdots \\ W(t_n) \end{pmatrix}$ is a Gaussian vector.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks good for the most part. However, it should be noted that two random variables being normal and having zero covariance does not imply independence. Wikipedia even has a nicely titled page for [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).

Your calculation can be justified, however. The key point is that the standard Brownian motion taken at any two times $s,t$ produces two *jointly Gaussian* variables. It suffices to show that two jointly Gaussian variables are uncorrelated to show independence.

EDIT: Justification of independent increments.

Consider any two disjoint increments $[s_1, t_1]$ and $[s_2, t_2]$ of the process $(X)_t = B_{1-t} - B_1$. We want to show that $Y_1 = X_{t_1} - X_{s_1} = B_{1-t_1} - B_{1-s_1} $ is independent of $Y_2 = X_{t_2} - X_{s_1} = B_{1-t_2} - B_{1-s_2} $. It's actually easier to forego the covariance calculation. 
$Y_1 = B_{1-t_1} - B_{1-s_1}$ is the random variable tracking the Brownian motion in the time period $[1 - t_1, 1 - s_1]$ (we've flipped the endpoints as the negative of a standard Brownian motion is also a standard Brownian motion). Similarly, $Y_2 = B_{1-t_2} - B_{1-s_2}$ is the random variable tracking the Brownian motion in the time period $[1 - t_2, 1 - s_2]$. Since $[s_1, t_1]$ and $[s_2, t_2]$ are disjoint by assumption, the intervals $[1 - t_1, 1 - s_1]$ and $[1 - t_2, 1 - s_2]$ are also disjoint, and hence by the independent increments property of the standard Brownian motion, $Y_1 = B_{1-t_1} - B_{1-s_1}$ and $Y_2 = B_{1-t_2} - B_{1-s_2}$ must be independent too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I can't understand how to use your argument, could you please extend it a bit more? @paulinho

Comment: Your goal is to show the independent increments property of a Brownian motion, so you calculated the covariance between two arbitrary disjoint increments. In general, zero covariance between two random variables is not sufficient for independence (and I suspect you know this), but you justified this by saying the Brownian motions at $s$ and $t$ are normally distributed. As described above, even this is not true. It's the fact that the Brownian motions are jointly Gaussian that allows you to make the claim that zero covariance implies independence.

Comment: Yes sure that's clear to me. What I wanted to say is that I can't understand how to adjust my argument to prove the independence of increments...

Comment: I've added a sample proof of independent increments. A proof that calculates the covariance is only useful given the fact that the distribution of $B_x$ for $x = s,t$ are jointly Gaussian variables. If you wanted to prove the previous statement, we would have basically already shown that $B_{1-t} - B_1$ has independent increments, so I've shown a more concise proof.

Comment: Thanks @paulinho, it's clear now! I just edited my answer adding the proof that the process $W_t$ is Gaussian, i.e. by seeing the vector as a linear map of a Gaussian vector. Could you please tell me if everything is okay?

Comment: could you give me a check?

Comment: Looks good - nice job!

Comment: thanks for the feedback! :)